# How to read a 3x3 matrix in Java untill all elements are null?

Tags: java, matrix

I'm new to java and have a small problem. I need to read a set of 3x3 java matrix and print it. Nothing special here. Problem is that I have to read it until I reach a matrix that has all elements null and print all matrixes and their determinant. I have a problem reading null values and checking if all are nulls. Any suggestions?

LE: This is what I have so far. But I need to repeat this process until all elements are null

```
import java.io.*;
class Matrix3x3
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader BR=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader (System.in));
        int Number[][]=new int[3][3];
        int i,j;
        String m;
        System.out.println("Enter Elements for Matrix 3x3 :");
        for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
            {
                m=BR.readLine();
                if (m == null)
                    {
                        m="0";
                    }
                Number[i][j]=Integer.parseInt(m);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Elements in Matrix are : ");
                                System.out.println("");
        for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        {
            for(j=0;j<=2;j++)
            {
                System.out.print(Number[i][j]+"\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        int determinantMatrix = determinant(Number, 3 ,3);
        System.out.print("Determinant is: "determinantMatrix+"\n");
    }

    public static int determinant(int[][] result, int rows, int cols) {
    if (rows == 2)
        return result[0][0] * result[1][1] - result[0][1] * result[1][0];

    int determinant1 = 0, determinant2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        int temp = 1, temp2 = 1;
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
            temp *= result[(i + j) % cols][j];
            temp2 *= result[(i + j) % cols][rows - 1 - j];
        }

        determinant1 += temp;
        determinant2 += temp2;
    }

    return determinant1 - determinant2;
}
}
```

Comment: Please be more descriptive. What is the source of input? what is the data structure used? what is the present code that tries to achieve this?

Comment: If *all* elements are null? How would you calculate the determinant if only *some* elements are null?

Comment: source of input is user input. if some elements are null They would be taken into consideration as 0 I guess

Comment: It’s a very broad question as long as you are not giving us more precision and you’re not being more specific about where your challenge lies. For example, user input, is that from a console or a GUI or something yet different?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I've edited the first question

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the edit, I understand much better now what you mean by “I have a problem reading null values and checking if all are nulls.”

You are checking if the result returned from `BufferedReader.readLine()` is `null`. This will not tell you whether the user has entered a null value, since the only time `readLine()` returns `null` is when the end of the input stream is reached (which doesn’t happen easily/normally on the console).

Wait a second, what would it mean that the user has entered a null value? You need to decide this first. One option is you allow the user to type the word “null”. Then check using `m.equals("null")`. This would work. Another option is regarding user input of 0 as null, but this would not be acceptable if you need to distinguish between a matrix of all zeroes and a matrix of all nulls.

Next, how do you check if the matrix contains all nulls? Your current code has filled in 0 for `null`. So the easy answer is you check if the matrix contains all zeroes. One way to think of it is search for a non-zero value, if you don’t find it, there are all zeroes. As indicated before, if you need to distinguish between a matrix of all zeroes and a matrix of all nulls, this approach is not a good one. In this case you may for example declare your matrix `Integer[][]` instead of `int[][]`. This would allow you to fill in `null` values and distinguish them from non-null values (including zeroes).